# AJAX using PHP - Different ways to structure?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Have a question.  I am learning AJAX right now and I see that on w3schools the way they have the PHP and MySQL AJAX stuff as examples is the AJAX makes a call to a separate PHP file on the server and then that PHP sends back whatever you want to pull.  The example I see is a table is returned with rows and columns based on the query.

**My question is**, does using AJAX with PHP and MySQL require you to set it up this way (meaning sending data to a separate php page and then getting a return on the current page the AJAX was called from/started at)?

I have a project where I currently have multiple php pages.  Some of them being only 'processors' where they take in data and process it but do not spit out any html/text for the users and I have redirects set up to take the user back to a page, **BUT** then some of my php files have both html AND php handling the processing and spitting out stuff for the user to see on that page.

Ideally I would like to use AJAX and **for the pages that have both HTML and PHP** (user facing stuff on the page) I would like for AJAX to call the page its on and spit out the returned data from the database.  It is not a hard requirement but think it would save me time not having to refactor a lot of the structure, but if that is the only way or is a **better design/practice** then I will surely go that way.

Hope this question made sense, and as always **thanks for all help and ideas**.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. Hint: post effort and code. Right now this question does not lend itself to the format of SO. Also W3Schools is not a great resource. There are thousand of examples here at SO of how to structure PHO and AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your problem here, but I think a good way to organize your AJAX/php code is to create a kind of php API ( in a php file ), with a bunch of functions doing all the back end stuff, and then, in your AJAX calls, you specify which function you want to use.

Hope it can helps a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That does help and as mplungjan said earlier there are other similar questions so as I have been looking I am seeing that passing parameters to functions to handle the pulls is a good idea and probably less of a mess.

Comment: Glad I could help, Yeah I think it will be easier to maintain your website by separating clearly the front and the back-end.